# python if and if not command usage

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
path=os.getcwd()
list_dir=os.listdir(path+'//Osativa')
if not os.path.exists('results'):
    os.makedirs('results') 
fo1=open('./results/annotation.txt','w')
f1=open(path+'//CLEAN FILE.csv').readlines()
f2=open(path+'//Osativa//Osativa_323_v7.0.annotation_info.txt').readlines()
#num=0
for line in f1:
    locus_id=line.split(',')[1]
    if locus_id.startswith('LOC'):
        #num +=1
        #print(num)
        #print (locus_id)
        #num1=0
        for line1 in f2:
            if locus_id==line1.split()[1]:
                #num1+=1
                #print (num1)
                #print locus_id
                transcript=line1.split()[2]
                if transcript.startswith('LOC'):
                    #print (locus_id+'\t'+transcript)
                    for i in line1.split():
                         if i.startswith('PF'):
                              print (locus_id+'\t'+transcript+'\t'+i)
                              if not i.startswith('PF'):
                                  print (locus_id+'\t'+transcript+'\t'+'\t')
```

My question is, if there is no PF id for a particular gene, I want to type tab key there (remain as a space). So how should I do that?
Also, I want to get this output into an excel file, so if some genes don't have a PF id, I can see a space there. I think my question can be understood. Finally, I want to get the output into another txt file

Comment: Do you know about the existence of `else`, `if`'s brother?

Comment: your indentation is incorrect... `if not i.startswith('PF'):` will never be run because it's inside a block code that runes only if `if i.startswith('PF'):`. Use what Force suggest, or proper indentation.

Comment: When your indentation is reaching all the way to the right of the screen, it's time to refactor your code a little.

Comment: Suggestions: use better variable names; extract your `for line1 in f2` loop into a function; use unpacking `_, locus_id, transcript, the_rest = line1.split(maxsplit=3)`; use this pattern: `with open(path+'//CLEAN FILE.csv') as f:  f1_lines = f.readlines()`

Answer (score 1):

you have problems with indentation, also it is better to use [`else` block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) here

```
for line in f1:
    locus_id = line.split(',')[1]
    if locus_id.startswith('LOC'):
        # num +=1
        # print(num)
        # print (locus_id)
        # num1=0
        for line1 in f2:
            if locus_id == line1.split()[1]:
                # num1+=1
                # print (num1)
                # print locus_id
                transcript = line1.split()[2]
                if transcript.startswith('LOC'):
                    # print (locus_id+'\t'+transcript)
                    for i in line1.split():
                        if i.startswith('PF'):
                            print(locus_id + '\t' + transcript + '\t' + i)
                        else:
                            print(locus_id + '\t' + transcript + '\t' + '\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, your `for` loop and `if` logic are a bit jumbled. I'm not sure what the exact behavior should be, so here's a suggestion.

```
# print the common part first with no trailing newline
# using a format string
print('{}\t{}\t'.format(locus_id, transcript), end='')
for i in line1.split():
    if i.startswith('PF'):
        print(i)
        # this stops after the first match, your code would
        # print for each match found. Not sure what you want.
        break
# for loop else, means if there was no "break"
else:
    print('\t')
```

What's it supposed to do?

1. only print once if a `PF` is found
2. print for each `PF` found
3. optionally print the line with the `\t` for each element that isn't a `PF`

As an example of refactoring, create a function to extract the `PF` or return TAB.

```
def get_first_PF(items):
    for i in items:
        if i.startswith('PF'):
            return i
    return '\t'
```

Then, your code in that block becomes this:

```
print('{}\t{}\t{}'.format(
    locus_id,
    transcript,
    get_first_PF(line1.split())
))
```